# Laravel DB : first() method brings the Response content must be a string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I use Laravel Illuminate and I get this error when I use the first() method to get a single result:

`The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

```
return DB::table('todos')->where("title","your List")->first();
```

If i select with the get() method it works:

```
return DB::table('todos')->where("title","your List")->get();
```

do you know what's wrong with the first statement?

Answer (score 5):

When you do `->get()`, you get an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` object back. This object can be returned by the response, since it implements a `__toString()` method:

```
/**
 * Convert the collection to its string representation.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->toJson();
}

/**
 * Get the collection of items as JSON.
 *
 * @param  int  $options
 * @return string
 */
public function toJson($options = 0)
{
    return json_encode($this->jsonSerialize(), $options);
}

/**
 * Convert the object into something JSON serializable.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return array_map(function ($value) {
        if ($value instanceof JsonSerializable) {
            return $value->jsonSerialize();
        } elseif ($value instanceof Jsonable) {
            return json_decode($value->toJson(), true);
        } elseif ($value instanceof Arrayable) {
            return $value->toArray();
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }, $this->items);
}
```

As you can see, all it does it convert the entire collection to json.

But when you do `->first()`, what happens behind the scenes is that Laravel does `->take(1)->get()->first()`, so that the query is restricted to one row, then a collection containing the result from that one row is retrieved, and finally you get an object back.

So the `->first()` call is made on the collection behind the scenes, meaning you don't get another collection back, but rather a database object - probably of the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` kind, I can't quite remember.

And since that class doesn't implement a `__toString()` method, the response doesn't know what to do with it. Instead, you get an error.

You can easily simulate the same response by either running `json_encode()` on the object, or by returning a json response.

Comment: When selecting a single row using `DB`, you'll get an object of `stdClass`, which doesn't implement `__toString()`.

Comment: You could also just use the JSON response. `return response()->json(compact('todo'));`

Answer (score 0):

@JoelHinz already put it well as detailed as possible. But being curious about this behaviour I found something interesting in Laravel doc under [Query builder's where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

[image]

Using `DB` Facade and calling a `get()` returns a collection of (StdClass) object. And since it resides in Laravel's collection, there are methods of converting its underlying property to String. But when you access one of the items in the collection directly from query Builder, then you have a *pure* StdClass object which does not implement `__toString()` (pretty sure).

I think the same situation is if you have a collection, and you retrieve one of the underlying array say `$collection[0]` you will lose the implementation of `_toString()` of Laravel's collection since you already unwrap it and now have pure PHP array.

This behaviour is just how the Query builder is developed. In order to have your query result treated well, you can `return json_encode($query_result)`, `return response()->json($query_result)`, or use Eloquent (if you have a model created), i.e `return Todo::where("title","your List")->first()`;

Answer (score -2):

You just have to execute the sql query and extract the result from position zero 0

```
return DB::select('sql')[0];
```

Comment: Always give explanation of your answers

Comment: @LeenaPatel Although giving an explanation is highly recommend, and makes it more likely an answer is useful (and thus gets upvoted instead of downvoted), a code-only answer is still considered an answer, so during review you should vote "Looks OK".